# Extra column in bootstrap table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, bootstrap-4

Why there is an extra column in the table? [image: table image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <center>
    <a href="./" class="btn btn-primary">
      <i class="far fa-hand-point-left"></i> Back
    </a>
    <br /><br />
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-responsive">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Sr.</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Contact</th>
          <th>City</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>
            Name</td>
          <td>Email Id (Mobile Number)</td>
          <td>City</td>
          <td><button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" disabled>Waiting for Directory</button></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>
            Name</td>
          <td>Email Id (Mobile Number)</td>
          <td>City</td>
          <td><a href="?ua=trial" class="btn btn-large" style="background-color: red;color: white;">Block</a></td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>

  </center>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Why there is an extra column in the table? [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tHsi.png)

Also, why there is scrollbar when screen is small? (It should adjust itself with the screen as I am using **table-responsive**.)

Comment: There's not an extra column, the table is left aligned by default. Are you trying to make it centered or full-width?

Comment: @Zim the table should be centered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `.table-responsive` class to the parent. not on table

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: you want full width table?

Comment: No auto width, but in center

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.table-responsive` or add style attribute on *table tag* `display : table`